# PHP Class Definition with Data Structure

Tags: php, oop, object

What I'm trying to do is the following... Include the *CLASS FILE* in one of my other classes, then do the following:

```
    $zSubscription = new zSubscription();
    $zSubscription->Account->AccountNumber = "ABCD-230948";
    $zSubscription->BillToContact->Address1= "123 Dirt Lane Road";
    $this->createContact($zSubscription);


public function createContact($subscriptionObj){
    if (strlen($subscriptionObj->Account->AccountNumber) > 10){
        // Do something special
        echo "Batch Processing<br />";
        if ($subscriptionObj->Account->Batch == "Batch1"){
            echo "Running Batch 1";
        }
    }
}
```

The BATCH1 should be set (That is the expected result)  Currently it is not set.

The class file to be included via require_once is below:

```
/**
* Zuora Definition Class
* @author Will H
* @license MIT
*/

class Account{
    /** @var string */
    public $AccountNumber  = null;
    /** @var bool */
    public $AllowInvoiceEdit   = true;
    /** @var bool */
    public $AutoPay = true;
    /** @var string */
    public $Batch    = "Batch1";
    /** @var string */
    public $BcdSettingOption    = "ManualSet";
    /** @var int */
    public $BillCycleDay     = 31;
    /** @var string */
    public $CrmId;
    /** @var string */
    public $Currency = "USD";
    /** @var string */
    public $CustomerServiceRepName = "Online Order";
    /** @var string */
    public $Name;
    /** @var string */
    public $PaymentTerm = "Due Upon Receipt";
    /** @var string */
    public $PurchaseOrderNumber = null;
    /** @var string */
    public $SalesRepName = "Online Order";
}

class PaymentMethod{ 
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardAddress1;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardAddress2;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardCity;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardCountry;
    /** @var int */
    public $CreditCardExpirationMonth;
    /** @var int */
    public $CreditCardExpirationYear;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardHolderName;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardNumber;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardPostalCode;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardState;
    /** @var string */
    public $CreditCardType;
    /** @var string */
    public $Type = 'CreditCard';
}
class BillToContact{

    /** @var string */
    public $Address1;
    /** @var string */
    public $Address2;
    /** @var string */
    public $City;
    /** @var string */
    public $Country;
    /** @var string */
    public $FirstName;
    /** @var string */
    public $LastName;
    /** @var string */
    public $PostalCode;
    /** @var string */
    public $State;
    /** @var string */
    public $WorkEmail;
    /** @var string */
    public $WorkPhone;

}
class SubscribeOptions{
    /** @var bool */
    public $GenerateInvoice = true;
    /** @var bool */
    public $ProcessPayments = true;
}

class Subscription{
    /** @var bool */
    public $AutoRenew = true;
    /** @var string */
    public $ContractAcceptanceDate;
    /** @var string */
    public $ContractEffectiveDate;
    /** @var int */
    public $InitialTerm = 12;
    /** @var int */
    public $RenewalTerm = 12;
    /** @var string */
    public $ServiceActivationDate;
    /** @var string */
    public $TermStartDate;
}
class RatePlan{
    /** @var string */
    public $ProductRatePlanId;
}
class RatePlanData{
    /** @var RatePlan */
    public $RatePlan;
}
class SubscriptionData{
    /** @var Subscription */
    public $Subscription;
    /** @var RatePlanData */
    public $RatePlanData;
}
class zSubscription{
    /** @var Account */
    public $Account;
    /** @var PaymentMethod */
    public $PaymentMethod;
    /** @var BillToContact */
    public $BillToContact;
    /** @var SubscribeOptions */
    public $SubscribeOptions;
    /** @var SubscriptionData */
    public $SubscriptionData;
}

?>
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I really can't figure out what you want to do. Are you looking for something like inheritance? Try to write a before and after `dump()` scenario, in psuedo-code if needed.

Comment: I added the edit above to clarify what I'm trying to do.  Since I suck at commenting...

Comment: I added another edit clarify more... Based on the edit above I want to be able to have access to the public class variables in order to do a check against `$object->Account->Currency == "USD"` even though I did not set the actual value as in the example above.

Comment: I don't really understand it either. It sounds as though you're attempting to nest objects within objects, so that you can iterate over their hierarchy. Is this correct? If this is the case, you'll want to instantiate your member objects in your zSubscription constructor. That way, default values are set when you create your main object.

Comment: I re-edited the post to make the question simpler.

Comment: As for the previous questions yes I'm trying to inherit the base class values.  And get a full object struct with all predefined variables pre set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say, that your code is leaking encapsulation, would be an understatement. There is no encapsulation at all. You could replace your "objects" with an array, and call it a day.

In a well written class, you would have only `private` and `protected` variables. They are available only though *Getters* and *Setters*, and even then you had to it carefully. You should read this article: ["GetterEradicator" *by Martin Fowler*](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/GetterEradicator.html).

Another issue in you code is that you seem to do some voodoo in the constructors. Take a look at this example:

```
$zSubscription = new zSubscription();
$zSubscription->Account->AccountNumber = "ABCD-230948";
$zSubscription->BillToContact->Address1= "123 Dirt Lane Road";
```

Where did the `Account` and `BillToContact` come from? You are exposing objects *(which where created in `zSubscription::__construct()` method .. and thus causing tight coupling to the names of two classes)* to completely unrelated context. This is [Law of Demeter](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter) violation, which results in leaky abstraction.

Comment: Great answer,  What I was trying to achieve was a merged array of data from data inheritance but also element type specifications.  Arrays you can stick any type of data you want in them without knowing what the data will be.  With classes and doc books you can still do the same but most modern IDE's will give you a popup of the element's type for instance AccountNumber in the list above could have been a string, however if the class @var was set to int... it would be easily identifiable.  Prior to this answer I just moved everything into ini files which does a RAW ini file read to array.